# Suggestion: Integrating Amazon Cognito with AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I've built an application which is connected with Amazon Cognito to take the sign in and sign-ups of users. Currently, application support three different subscriptions (Free, Basic, Premium). If the user signs in for basic Subscriptions, I want to give them least access to DynamoDB for download the parts of applications which is required to run the application service.

How to connect DynamoDB with Cognito directly
I am not sure, what's the best approach to follow this scenario?

(Please note- this is not a mobile-based application, so do not give suggestion to use AWS Amplify or relatable services)

Comment: What do you mean by "give them least access"? Wouldn't it be your application that communicates with DynamoDB, rather than the users interacting directly? In such a case, it would be the responsibility of your application to determine what functionality users can access.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I believe the question may be confusing the role of Cognito.  This point once confused me as well.  As you know, it is possible to restrict DynamoDB access based on a user's cognito identity id.  However,  that is not the same thing as restricting access to users of the application to free/basic/premium tiers.  While the distinction may be subtle, it's an understandably confusing distinction when first working with Cognito.  As you pointed out, the type of functionality Moi is inquiring about needs to happen in the business logic of the application, not in Cognito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I was first learning about Cognito, I had made the same set of assumptions you are currently making.  I knew that User Pools could act as my application's user directory, and Identity Pools would magically unlock *all* my authorization needs.  I was mistaken :)

At the risk of oversimplifying, AWS Cognito exists to answer two questions:

- Who are you? (authentication)
- What can you do? (authorization)

Cognito addresses these concerns with two distinct offerings: User Pools (authentication) and Identity Pools (authorization).

At a high level, User Pools let you handle user registration, authentication, account recovery, and supports authentication with third-party identity providers like Facebook, Google, etc.  Sounds like you might have this part figured out.

Cognito Identity Pools, on the other hand, provides a way to authorize users to use various AWS services. You can think of it as a vending machine for handing out AWS credentials. For example, if you needed to give your users access to upload a file to an S3 bucket or to invoke an endpoint in API Gateway, you could do so with an Identity Pool.  You can even [allow item-level access to DynamoDB based on an Amazon Cognito ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_items.html). However, this might not work the way you expect since your application users are probably not directly connecting to DynamoDB.

In most web/mobile applications, users are not connecting *directly* to DynamoDB.  Instead, they are interacting with a web/mobile app that communicates to the back-end of your application via an API.  That API would then communicate with DynamoDB.  If your stack is in AWS, the path may look something like this:

```
Client (web/mobile app) <-> API Gateway <-> Lambda <-> DynamoDB
```

In this architecture, your users would authenticate via Cognito.  Cognito would then authorize the user to make calls to API Gateway.  API Gateway would execute your lambda, which would then interact with DynamoDB.  The "user" of DynamoDB in this example is your Lambda, *not* the user of your application.

That last bit is important, so I'll repeat it: Unless your users are *directly* connecting to DynamoDB (not recommended), they are not the "user" operating on DynamoDb.  Therefore, restricting DynamoDB access based on a user's Cognito ID is not going to be an option for you.

So, what can you do?  Your application needs to provide the business logic around what effect your users can have on DynamoDB.  Perhaps free users have read-only access to a specific partition, while premium users can modify the same partition.  That logic has to be handled directly by you.

I know you said you weren't looking for Amplify suggestions since your application is not mobile-based.  However, Amplify offers SDKs that aren't specific to mobile development.  The folks at Serverless have made a [fantastic tutorial](https://serverless-stack.com/) on building a full-stack serverless web app, which includes a very [readable chapter on serverless auth with Cognito](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/handling-auth-in-serverless-apis.html).  They use Amplify in a web app to integrate with Cognito, S3, and API Gateway.  If that's something you are trying to do, I'd recommend checking it out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out. I have been using that pattern with cognito for a while, nevertheless those links are interesting.

Comment: It's a Desktop Application. So, I am not sure, how things work. Could you suggest a way in a Desktop Application for storing and uploading a file from the Server?

Comment: If you are developing a desktop app, you'll still be using the AWS SDKs for your chosen programming language to access S3, Cognito, etc.  I found a project on github from a past Amazon Re:Invent conference that shows how to integrate Cognito with Java and .Net desktop applications (https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-java-desktop-app).  There is also a tutorial linked in the readme of the github repository.

Comment: The general approach I outlined above still applies to a desktop application.  You do not "connect" DynamoDB (or any AWS resource) to Cognito.  Rather, you use Cognito to obtain credentials that can be used to access AWS resources.  A @John Rotenstein correctly pointed out in his comment, your application will be the integration point between these services.

Comment: Thanks for writing this out Seth, it's a great explanation. I slightly disagree on "Restricting DynamoDB access based on a user's Cognito ID is not going to be an option for you.". Im currently trying to restrict users (authed with congitor) requesting API Gateway to only their records in a table. Why is it not possible to pass the cognito ID to the API Gateway lambda and restrict to that value? Yes the lambda has to have full table access, but you could link the lambda to user a cognito users IAM policy?